# jQuery to show div from id attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have two inputs

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Store Username <span>*</span></label>
  <input required type="text" name="storeusername" class="form-control info" id="1" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Store Name<span>*</span></label>
  <input required type="text" name="storename" class="form-control info" id="2" />
</div>
```

What I am doing is that I when I click on an input it should first hide all divs and then pick id of that input and show its respective div…

divs are these

```
<div id="div1" class="infoDiv hidden">
  <div class="company-story-content"><h2 class="story-title">Store <span class="color-text">Username</span></h2></div>
  <p>Store username is unique and it will be used to find your store.</p>
  <p>For example www.flashcart.com/<span class="color-text">abc</span> to find store that has <span class="color-text">abc</span> username.</p>
  <p>Please keep in mind before choosing username.</p>
  <p>
    <ul>
      <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Username can contain <span class="color-text">Alphabets</span><li>
      <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Username can contain <span class="color-text">Numbers</span>.</li>
      <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Username can contain <span class="color-text">Underscores</span>.</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="infoDiv hidden">
  <div class="company-story-content"><h2 class="story-title">Some other<span class="color-text">Username</span> </h2></div>
  <p>Div</p>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".info").click(function() {
    var id = $(".info").attr('id');
    $(".infoDiv").hide();
    $("#div"+id).removeClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

But this is not working! No div is shown. Can anyone help me out with a bit of explanation?

Comment: Try: var id = $(this).attr('id'); to gett current/clicked element id....

Comment: No. it doesn't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your intention is to bring up a `div` when user is about to enter values into the text box.

Since users can navigate into the text box with keyboard too I would recommend you to use **focus** event to trigger the logic of bringing up the div rather than `click`.

```
$(".info").on('focus',function()
{
   $(".infoDiv").hide();
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   $("#div"+id).show();
});
```

Comment: @Alexis glad to help.. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your 'hidden' classes look like so I used inline styles to hide the divs and then jquery to show/hide similar to how you're already doing it.  See fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/jkkr7efh/

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Store Username <span>*</span></label>
  <input required type="text" name="storeusername" class="form-control info" id="1" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Store Name<span>*</span></label>
  <input required type="text" name="storename" class="form-control info" id="2" />
</div>

<div id="div1" class="infoDiv" style="display:none;">
  <div class="company-story-content"><h2 class="story-title">Store <span class="color-text">Username</span> </h2></div>
  <p>Store username is unique and it will be used to find your store.</p>
  <p>For example www.flashcart.com/<span class="color-text">abc</span> to find store that has <span class="color-text">abc</span> username.</p>
  <p>Please keep in mind before choosing username.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Username can contain <span class="color-text">Alphabets</span><li>
    <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Username can contain <span class="color-text">Numbers</span>.</li>
    <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Username can contain <span class="color-text">Underscores</span>.</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="div2" class="infoDiv" style="display:none;">
  <div class="company-story-content">
    <h2 class="story-title">Some other<span class="color-text">Username</span> </h2></div>
  <p>Div</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
      {
        $(".info").click(function(event)
        {
          $(".infoDiv").hide();
          var id = $(event.target).attr('id');
          $("#div"+id).show();
        });
      });
```

Comment: Instead of passing `event` in, you can also just use `this`. The key to your solution is that you're using `.show()` instead of removing a class. The jQuery functions don't add a class, but change inline stylings.

Comment: Krillgar it achieves the same result! This could work. Previously I made separate functions for all divs. Now wanted to create more intelligent code. This works this does it then

Answer (score 2):

.hide() and .show() are different mechanisms from having or removing a "hidden" class.  Try changing your last line to:
    $("#div"+id).removeClass("hidden").show();

Comment: That's why the last line is not working. However, the comments are correct about needing to use `this` to find the `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the jQuery .hide() function is not the same as adding the hidden class to hide the divs, so removing your hidden class isn't going to show them. You can either hide and show by adding and removing the class, or by using the jQuery .hide() and .show() functions. Don't mix he methods or it will give you trouble.